# How to Initialize dyinamic vectors and call them using Eigen library vectors in c++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, eigen

I'm quite new with c++ and I'm struggling when calling some vectors and variables. I'm using Eigen library and my idea is to have all initialization variables in the header file and call them from my main script in order to organize the code.

So, these are all the variables I want to call. Searching through internet, I have seeing that one method could be using structures but I'm not sure how could I do that. I made a try but it doesnt work with vector variables. I need to initialize them as a vector of vectors of 6xi (size could change depending another function).

```
 #pragma once

#ifndef INIT_VARIABLES_H
#define INIT_VARIABLES_H

#include <vector>
#include "Eigen/Dense"

using namespace Eigen;

struct datastruct
{
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> posDesired(6);
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> velDesired(6);
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> posRobot(6);
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> ErrorRobot(6);
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> velRobot(6);
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> velRobotcalc(6);
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> errorPos(6);
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> errorVel(6);
    std::vector<float> errorAnt = { 0.0,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> P(6);
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> D(6);
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> I(6);
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> PIDOUT(6);
    std::vector<float> errorInt = { 0.0,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    std::vector<float> posRobotAnt = { 0.0,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
};

#endif // !INIT_VARIABLES_H
```

Is this a good way to initialize variables? And can I solve this issue with vectors?

EDIT: I forgot saying that the error is "type identifier expected"

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<float>> posDesired{6};` note `{}` not `()`.

Comment: Don't use `std::vector` to store fixed size arrays. There is `std::array` for that purpose. Also it doesn't look like you are doing anything with Eigen in this file. What exact issue are you having?

Comment: *If* you actually want to use Eigen, use `Eigen::Matrix<float, 6, 6>` or `Eigen::Matrix<float, 6, Eigen::Dynamic>` for 6x6 or 6xi matrices. If you have dynamically growing collections of 6d-vectors, also consider `std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<float, 6, 1> >` (really depends on what you plan to do with that).